# SSH connection refused from centos to debian

Tags: ssh, connection

I have very strange problem with my server.

I use ssh without problem on my SERVER_1, but when I try to connect SERVER_1 with SERVER_4, it answers "connection refused":

```
[root@server ~]# ssh root@XXXXXX.com -p 4022
ssh: connect to host XXXXXX.com port 4022: Connection refused
```

With -P it's work:

```
[root@server ~]# ssh root@XXXXX.com -P 4022
root@XXXXXX.com's password:
```

Why?

Obviously rsync does not work.

Comment: Following [these](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/291370/1783163) simple rules could improve your questions a lot. I suggest to follow them. I partially fixed your question now, but I can't be with you every time :-)

Answer (score 0):

> ssh root@XXXXX.com -P 4022

SSH does not accept any `-P` argument. It is just ignored and you are connecting to standard port `22`. Just drop this argument and you are fine.